# Catching js|css in nginx location regexp

Tags: regex, nginx, server

Anybody plaese explain me - why requst on that url -
`http://localhost/static/css/style.css`
 return **404**?

Here is part of my *nginx.conf*

```
location ~ /static/(?<doctype>[js|css]+) {

  # root /usr/src/app/public/;

  if ($doctype = "css") {
    set $contnt_type "text/css";
  }
  if ($doctype = "js") {
    set $contnt_type "text/javascript";
  }

  expires 30d;
  add_header X_Cached 1;
  access_log off;

  add_header Cache-Control "public";
  add_header  Content-Type   $contnt_type;

   return 200  "$doctype";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Should it be `$content_type` ?

Comment: Your regex looks wrong. `[` and `]` are used to define a character class. And, you have characters following a `$` which is the end of string anchor. Maybe something like this will work: `location ~ ^/static/(?<doctype>js|css)/ { ... }`

Comment: Your regex contains **many** mistakes. What do you want to capture into the `$doctype` variable on `http://localhost/static/css/style.css` URL? What do you want to be returned?

Comment: @IvanShatsky i want to catch one of two variants of subpath - it 'css' or 'js' is placed after `/static/` in request_uri

Comment: I understand that you want to process *.js and *.css files with this location. What result you achieve in `$doctype` variable when you get `http://localhost/static/css/style.css` request?

Comment: @RichardSmith, thanks! your answer halped, now its works fine

Comment: @IvanShatsky i try to achive changing `$cotnt_type` variable  by value of `$doctype` in `if` block to set it in `Content-Type' header

Comment: And what you expect from this directive: `return 200 "$doctype"`? Where are your assets physicaly located? I thing you should use `try_files` here.

Comment: @IvanShatsky it string just for check what was catched in `$doctype`. insted it i want to use `alias /usr/src/app/static/dist/$doctype;`

Comment: Then my solution should work, the only thing I'm not sure should it be `alias /usr/src/app/static/dist/$doctype;` or `alias /usr/src/app/static/dist/$doctype/;`, try second variant first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are less complicated than you want them to be.
Changing `Content-Type` based on a file extension is a trivial task in NGINX and you don't need a dedicated location to achieve that.

Simply edit `/etc/nginx/mime.types` with the desired value of `Content-Type` header based on file extension, e.g.:

```
types {
    text/html       html htm shtml;
    text/css        css;
    text/javascript js;     
    ...
}
```

Needless to say, editing that file will result in the `Content-Type` values specified for the entire NGINX installation. Which is fine, for most cases.

If you indeed want to alter `Content-Type` in a *specific* location (which I really don't see why, but putting it for completeness), you can do this as well, like so (assuming you know all the possible file types in a given location):

```
location /static/ {
  types { 
     text/css css;
     text/javascript js; 
     # be sure to add any extra file types you have below:
     # ...
  }   

  expires 30d;
  add_header X_Cached 1;
  access_log off;

  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would better use the [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block instead of `if` construction, [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)!

```
map $doctype $contnt_type {
    js    "text/javascript";
    css   "text/css";
}

server
    ...
    location ~ ^/static/(?<doctype>js|css)/ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header X-Cached 1;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header Content-Type  $contnt_type;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for halp. but alias with regexp is worked strange ) 
in last arg in row `alias /usr/src/app/public/static/$doctype` i see only one letter of $doctype it `c` or `j`. That why finaly i just use the `root` directive.

Comment: Maybe this was because of error in your regex and already changed after replacing square brackets to round ones?